# Different ways to implement Workbox?

Tags: workbox

I have seen many code examples of Workbox [[3]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PL2DG9LJoVQ&app=desktop)[[4]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dGWoffJcFhg) and it seems like they all just how different ways of implementing same workbox functionality. So you can:

- Create your own custom file + `injectManifest` from `workbox-build` or `workbox-cli`
- Create your own custom file with precache list with `workbox-precaching` [[1]](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-precaching#explanation_of_the_precache_list), custom routes with `workbox-routing` [[2]](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-routing#how_to_register_a_regular_expression_route)
- Create service worker file purely from `workbox-cli` / `workbox-build`

Am I right, or I misunderstood everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using precaching is optional, and most of the methods that you describe assume that you will be using precaching. If you *do* choose to using precaching, then integrating with build tools to create that precache manifest is a requirement.

Otherwise, you can just use pieces of Workbox from a hand-crafted service worker file to implement only, e.g., [routing and runtime response strategies](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/route-requests).